# Cannot setup AdventureWorks for SQL Server Management Studio 17

Tags: sql-server

[image]

Always getting the error "No backup selected to be restored" though I have selected the correct backup file having .bak extension. I cannot understand why this is happening

Comment: Don't you have to specify where you want it to go?

Comment: @shawnt00 yes, you do. Also, OP, SSMS 2017 isn't a version of SQL Server, it's an application used to interact with SQL Server 2008+.

Comment: How can I resolve this error?